# Couchbase N1q1 update array element and return only the updated block

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I want to update an element in an array object and return only the few elements from the updated array object.

Document:

```
{
"doctype" : "report",
"name":"nick",
"emailId":"nick123@gmail.com",
"subjects" : [{
   "name":"SOA",
   "tutor":"roshan",
   "classes" : "12",
    "mark" : 40,
    "subid": "5678"
 },
 {
   "name":"UNIX",
   "tutor":"mathew",
   "classes" : "9"
    "mark" : 50,
    "subid" : "3788"    
 }
],
"id" : "12345"
}
```

n1q1:

```
update bucket1 
   Set i.status = “pass” for i in subjects when i.mark > 40 end
where doctype = "report"
returning *
```

above query returns the whole document but I want only few element from the updated array object like below. Can you please help me on this . Thanks

Expected query response

```
{
 "id" : "12345",
 "subid: “3788”,
 "name":"UNIX"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Returning clause you can build expression that you want.
You are updating ARRAY, it means it can update more than one element. so you can return as ARRAY, if you want FIRST element replace with ARRAY with FIRST.

```
UPDATE bucket1 AS b
SET i.status = "pass" FOR i IN b.subjects WHEN i.mark > 40 END
WHERE b.doctype = "report" AND (ANY v IN b.subjects SATISFIES v.mark > 40 END)
RETURNING (ARRAY {v.id, v.subid, v.name} FOR v IN b.subjects WHEN v.mark > 40 END) AS subjects;
```

You can only return modified info, you will not able to return original info.

Comment: So  if the update query changes the value of the parameter which is in the when condition then we cannot return element just from the updated array object right?. for example 

I want update an array element status = “PASS” when the mark is greater than 40 and status is “TBD” and return the subid from the updated array object. So excepted  values is    {“subid" : "3788"  }. is this possible

Comment: Document 

{
"doctype" : "report",
"name":"nick",
"emailId":"nick123@gmail.com",
"subjects" : [{
   "name":"SOA",
   "tutor":"roshan",
   "classes" : "12",
    "mark" : 40,
    "subid": "5678"
    “status” : “failed”
 },
 {
   "name":"UNIX",
   "tutor":"mathew",
   "classes" : "9"
    "mark" : 50,
    "subid" : "3788"    
    “status” :  “TBD”
 }
{
   "name”:”JAVA”,
   "tutor":"mathew",
   "classes" : "9"
    "mark" : 50,
    "subid" : "3789”    
    “status” :  “Pass”
 }


],
"id" : "12345"
}

Comment: During RETURNING clause evaluation you have only updated document not original document. If need that write select query or get document keys then use SDK get whole document do update using KV update. then you have both original and new document.